# notepad and notepad++ don't show same thing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have exported text from Excel in Unicode, like this:

[image]

then I edit with Notepad++ and change it to my desired form and save it as UTF-8 like this:

[image]

but when open it it in Notepad it is in completely different form?

In notepad++ I replaced `\t|\t` by `\n`1`` and also try `\p`1 `` etc, I have same problem in UltraEdit too, how can I solve it?

Comment: [text3 in notepad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAP6.png)
[text1](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1406476494)
[text3](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1406476711)

Comment: Can you provide the original file from Excel (the .xls file) and provide us with the information to make the text file?

Comment: i do as [this](https://surveygizmo.helpgizmo.com/help/pdfexport/id/517eb938fe775aa82f000004) file, but in save as type section select Unicode Text.

Comment: You want notepad.exe to show the same thing notepad++ does? Can you provide an example of how the form is different. Notepad++ will support more than notepad. If you are using unix line encoding notepad++ will look fine but notepad might squish it onto one line.

Comment: yes, i linked all of file in first comment, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAP6.png) is result.i need to compile final text by other program and if it has wrong form in notepad it can't be compile. the feature which i need exist in notepad and aren't odd that don't support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that `\n` character is used as end of line (EOL) character to represent a new line.

For [historical reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), Windows use two characters CR+LF (`\r\n`) to represent a new line, while Unix and Linux uses LF (`\n`).

Since notepad does not recognise `\n` alone, lines that looks separated in notepad++ becomes on the same line on notepad.

You can open up the file in notepad++, go to Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows Format to change all `\n` into `\r\n`, and then you should see the same thing from notepad.